# Validate a form before sending it to paypal using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, paypal

I am looking for advise in how to complete this task. I am trying to implement this (see example) in my website. Basically, just a form with a buy now button from paypal and before it is submitted, it has to be validated.

I do not see the problem. Any guidance would be really appreciated.

This is what I have so far!

```
<form id="unlockform" action=""https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"" method="post">

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="example@example.com">

<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

<!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Factory Unlock for iPhone">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="RCUnlocks_BuyNow_Unlock_US">

<!-- Provide a dropdown menu option field. -->
    <div id="error_messages"></div>
<label for="model">iPhone Model</label>
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Model"> <br />
<select id="model" name="os0">
<option value="Select your Model">-- Select your Model --</option>
<option value="iPhone 2G">iPhone 2G</option>
<option value="iPhone 3G">iPhone 3G</option>
<option value="iPhone 3GS">iPhone 3GS</option>
<option value="iPhone 4">iPhone 4</option>
<option value="iPhone 4S">iPhone 4S</option>
<option value="iPhone 5">iPhone 5</option>
</select> <br />

<!-- Provide a dropdown menu option field with prices. -->
<label for="services">Unlock Service</label>
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Service"> <br />
<select id="service" name="os1" class="required">
<option value="Sevice">-- Select your Service --</option>
<option value="Instant-90min">AT&amp;T Instant-90min max -  $6.25</option>
<option value="1-6Hrs">AT&amp;T 1-6 hours - $5.00</option>
<option value="1-24Hrs">AT&amp;T 1-24 hours - $3.50</option>
</select> <br />

<!-- Specify the price that PayPal uses for each option. -->
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Instant-90min">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="6.25">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="1-6Hrs">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="1-24Hrs">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="3.50">

    <label>IMEI #</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="IMEI#">
    <input type="text" name="os2" id="imeino" maxlength="15"    required="required" >
<br>        
<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" id="submit" src="paypal.gif"alt="PayPal -     The safer, easier way to pay online" >
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"  >

</form>
```

Here is my script!

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){


        jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element){
                error.appendTo(element.parent().find('div.error_messages'));
            }
        });



        $('#unlockform').validate({
            rules:{
                model:{
                    required:true
                },
                services:{
                    required: true
                },
                imeino:{
                    required: true,
                    number: true
                };


            },

            messages:{
                model:{
                    required: "Please select one option.<br>"
                },

                services:{
                    required: "Please select one option.<br>"
                },
                imeino:{
                    required: "You must enter your phone's IMEI#.",
                    number:"IMEI # must be numbers only!!!"
                }


            },

            errorContainer: "#error_messages",
            errorLabelContainer: "#error_messages"
        }); 

        submitHandler:function(){
            alert('Form validation was a success!')
        }


    });
</script>
```

Thank you all very much!

Here is a fiddle...[form](http://jsfiddle.net/robcabrera/3Kvqu/)

My problem is that the form doeS not get validated...!!

Comment: Good idea providing the JSFiddle, but it is not clear from your question what your actual problem is - don't make people try to guess! Please supply more info about what exactly is failing and what you want to happen.

Comment: Flubba thank you for your response. You see I am not trying to make people guess alright..I am just seeking some help. The problem is that the form does not get validated. Thank you

Comment: But Bob, when I hit run in the Fiddle and submit the form incomplete, it returns JSON which says it's invalid. This code appears to work fine and do precisely what you want so what is the problem? You have 25 views and no responses to your question. You have more chance of getting help if you can explain more clearly what is the matter. At the moment we can only guess.

Comment: Oh I see. I apologize for my question not being so clear. I have a form with two drop down options and an empty text field. If an item is not selected from the drop down , I want an error to be displayed. If the text field is not numbers only, another message should be displayed. When I click the submit button, nothing happens. It appears that the jQuery validate is not running. That is the problem. What I am trying to do is to validate the form  first and then submitted to paypal for payment.